# iOS - 'set start-with-shell off' issue when running iPhone application in simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I am getting the following error when trying to debug my iPhone application in the simulator.

> Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
>   fcntl$UNIX2003 called from function irc_connect in image KadeChat.
>   If you are encountering this problem running a simulator binary within gdb, make sure you 'set start-with-shell off' first.

I have done a bunch of Googling on this, and it seems that it might be a bug with the simulator. Does anyone know for sure?

I am building against the 4.2 version of the iOS SDK. Does upgrading to 4.3 fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

before this cleanAll build then

In xcode go to Project > set active executable > appname - Iphone 4.0 simulator

then open simulator then go to Hardware > version > 4.0.2

then double click urapptarget and in build tab change "ios deployment target = 4.0"

now run in simulator it will work